# Executing SQL statements using variables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SQL statement : "select case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end"

The above SQL statement need to be executed using variables as we have multiple statements like the above in a single table.

Row Column_name

1. ```
   case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end
   ```
2. ```
   case when 3=3 then 3 else 6 end
   ```

Can I do the above requirement without using javascript in Snowflake? If yes, how?

We are expecting to the output of the case statement not the string.
We have hundreds of merge statements inserted into a table. We want to execute them dynamically.

Comment: You should be able to do this using SQL scripting - but without you providing the full requirements, rather than just a code snippet, it's difficult to tell. Obviously, you can't just run a CASE statement, you have to run a full, valid, SQL statement

Comment: We have a table with merge SQL statement in each record. We need to run all the merge statements one after one using variables or other as there are hundreds of such statements and we can't run them individually. The merge statements are complete valid SQL statements. Can you provide a sample for the same? @NickW

Comment: Just query the table and then loop through the resultset and run EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<string_literal>' where '<string_literal>' is the value in your resultset.

Comment: Search for "working with loops" on the Snowflake documentation:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html#working-with-loops